# C# picking random string

Tags: c#

i basically just want to pick a random value in a string split by '|'.  I can't find a good example does anybody have an idea?

```
string[] mystrings = ("apple|orange|mayo|fruit|dog"):

string blah = "here i am "+resultsofrandom+" result chosen from mystring was " resultofrandom
```

obviously string blah is just an example, i just want the random chosen string from mystrings back into a new string...

Comment: So many of the same (right) answers. Can I just have a Dog? I know it's not random but heck, dogs rock.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
string[] mystrings = "apple|orange|mayo|fruit|dog".Split('|');
Random rnd = new Random();
string blah1 = mystrings[rnd.Next(mystrings.Length)];
string blah2 = mystrings[rnd.Next(mystrings.Length)];
string sentence = "here i am " + blah1 + " result chosen from mystring was " + blah2
```

Comment: Length minus 1?? `string blah = mystrings[rnd.Next(0, mystrings.Length - 1];`

Comment: No, Random.Next is exclusive of the upper bound. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx

Comment: How do I randomly choose a new value for Random each time, like if i want to do blah = int choice = new Random().Next(randommakework.Length); and then string blah2 = mystrings[rnd.Next(mystrings.Length)]; (but this is a new random.

Comment: use the same instance of Random each time. every call to .Next() gets you a new random number.

Comment: oh, i kept calling new randoms so i kept getting the same random.

Comment: here's an explanation for why that's happening: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654887/random-next-returns-always-the-same-values

Answer (score 6):

You could do this rather simply by splitting the string:

```
string[] mystrings = "apple|orange|mayo|fruit|dog".Split('|');
```

Then use a the `Random` class to pick one of those strings:

```
int choice = new Random().Next(mystrings.Length);
```

Now you can put it together:

```
string blah = "Your selection is: " + mystrings[choice];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Random rnd= new Random();
        int baseZeroArrayLen = 0;
        string[] mystrings = ("apple|orange|mayo|fruit|dog").Split('|');
        baseZeroArrayLen = mystrings.Length - 1; 
        int randomNumber = rnd.Next(baseZeroArrayLen);
        string rndString = mystrings[randomNumber];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var mystrings = ("apple|orange|mayo|fruit|dog").Split('|');
string blah = "here i am " + mystrings[new Random().Next(0, mystrings.Length)] + " result chosen..";
```

I think it will work as expected

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
string[] mystrings = ("apple|orange|mayo|fruit|dog").Split('|');
        Random randomInt = new Random();
            string blah = mystrings[randomInt.Next(mystrings.Length)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.Split()` to split up the delimited string and store each separate value in a string array. Then randomly pick an index into that array and display the corresponding string.

Answer (score 0):

Completely unnecessary LINQ alternative. Although the string.Format might be nice here.

```
string[] mystrings = "apple|orange|mayo|fruit|dog".Split('|');

string blah = string.Format("here i am {0} result chosen from mystring was {0}",
               mystrings.Skip(new Random().Next(mystrings.Length)).First());
```

Comment: You could do `mystrings.OrderBy(s => new Random().Next()).First();` as well.