# Disable and enable buttons in C#

Tags: c#

I am working on something fairly simple, well I thought it would be.
What I want is when button1 is clicked I want it to disable button1 and enable button2. I get the error below:
Error   1   Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

```
private readonly Process proc = new Process();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button2.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
            FileName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows) + "/explorer.exe",
            Arguments = @"D:\",
            UseShellExecute = false
        };
        proc.Start();
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = true;
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        proc.Kill();
        button1.Enabled = true;
        button2.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: What line do you get this error on?

Comment: Thanks everyone for putting up with some of my questions

Comment: Let's see how many people ignore reading the current correct answers and post the exact same answer.... ready ... go.

Comment: Please note that your code has an issue with `Random`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654887/random-next-returns-always-the-same-values

Comment: @gmcalab: The answers so far all were written at the same time basically.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions  "=" assign value to a variable "==" compares variable

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In your button1_click function you are using '==' for `button2.Enabled == true;`

This should be `button2.Enabled = true;`

Comment: Thank you, I would whether use this instead of in JS.

Answer (score 12):

`button2.Enabled == true ;` must be `button2.Enabled = true ;`.

You have a compare `==` where you should have an assign `=`.

Answer (score 5):

```
button2.Enabled == true ;
```

thats the problem - it should be:

```
button2.Enabled = true ;
```

Comment: It would be nice if the code view automatically had line-numbering applied. It took too long to visually find that.

Answer (score 5):

```
button2.Enabled == true ;
```

should be

```
button2.Enabled = true ;
```

Answer (score 5):

Change this

```
button2.Enabled == true
```

to

```
button2.Enabled = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

It is this line `button2.Enabled == true`, it should be `button2.Enabled = true`. You are doing comparison when you should be doing assignment.

Answer (score 1):

### Update 2019

This is now `IsEnabled`

```
 takePicturebutton.IsEnabled = false; // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for your purpose.

In parent form:

```
private void addCustomerToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CustomerPage f = new CustomerPage();
    f.LoadType = 1;
    f.MdiParent = this;
    f.Show();            
    f.Focus();
}
```

In child form:

```
public int LoadType{get;set;}

private void CustomerPage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    if (LoadType == 1)
    {
        this.button1.Visible = false;
    }
}
```