# Function or algorithm for random generation of objects in c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Is there a function or algorithm for generating objects from a list randomly in c#, something likea random generation of questions for a test, if you get the idea?

Comment: Have you looked into [`Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: this forum is for specific questions to programming problems.

Comment: "Generating" means creating to me. If they are in some list already, it's not about generating, only selecting them (at random or otherwise).

Comment: yes, and I couldn't figure out which of these methods to use :/

Comment: try :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310111/fast-random-number-generator-in-c-sharp or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234094/how-can-i-generate-truly-not-pseudo-random-numbers-with-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store your objects, e.g. strings in a list, then select a random number as the list index. Something like:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int idx = rnd.Next (0,myList.Length);
var randomObj = myList[idx];
```

Comment: `0` is redundant here (that's the default value anyway)

Comment: var stands for the type of the lists class?

Comment: True. Just added for more clarity. @Konrad Morawski

Comment: Yes, you can use var and it will be casted to the type of the object.