# Simple Heads/Tails in C#

Tags: c#, loops, random, while-loop

after reading some C# tutorials I decided to make a minigame of Heads/Tails. It generates a random number, 0 or 1, and writes out the result. Using a loop I repeat this a thousand times. The problem is that it would only write "heads" or "tails" depending on whether 0 or 1 gets generated more. For example if there are 535 "0s" and 465 "1s" it would only write down "Heads". Here is my code:

```
//variables
int count = 0;
int tails = 0;
int heads = 0;

while(count < 1000)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int result = rnd.Next(0,2);
    if(result == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Tails!");
        tails = tails + 1;
        count = count + 1;

    }
    else if(result == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Heads!");
        heads = heads + 1;
        count = count + 1;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Heads = " + heads + "Tails = " + tails + " Counts = " + count);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Don't create a new Random() inside your loop. Create it once at the start of the method, and call rnd.Next() inside the while loop.

Comment: Yet an other duplicate of [Random.Next returns always the same values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654887/random-next-returns-always-the-same-values)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random number generator only generating one random number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number)

Comment: Why the downvotes?  This is a real question, and is certainly on topic....

Comment: @cullub There's probably over 20 duplicates, on this site alone. Sounds pretty much like 'does not show any research effort' to me.

Comment: @cullub -- yes, I agree.  I didn't DV but it's definitely (well, probably) due to lack of research effort.

Comment: That's true.  However, the nature of the question seems to point out that he was on the wrong trail - he thought it had to do with how many of each.

Comment: @cullub -- Good point.  +1

Comment: Don't forget about the height of your console buffer... Just because you can only see that last few (hundred?) entries doesn't mean they all came out like that

Answer (score 4):

Try moving `Random rnd = new Random();` outside of the while loop:

```
Random rnd = new Random();

while (count < 1000)
//...
```

The problem is that there are no *true* random numbers in computers; they all work off of a list of previously-generated random numbers.  Since you are instantiating `Random` every loop, you're essentially picking the same start seed every time.  By using just one instance of `Random`, created outside of the loop, then your application will truly behave as if the numbers are being generated randomly.

**EDIT:**  To echo what Solal Pirelli said in the comments, the instance of `Random` is actually being seeded using the current computer system's time (if you don't give it any seed value in the constructor); however, since the loop iterations are happening so quickly, each instance created for each loop iteration has the same seed.

**EDIT #2:** As CalebB pointed out, it's also a good practice to provide your own seed to your `Random` instance via its other constructor.  I would suggest using the hash value from a GUID:

```
Random rnd = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
```

This *essentially* guarantees that each of your instances of `Random` will always be seeded differently, even if you create new instances in quick succession.  I say *essientially* because, while statistically very VERY low in probability, there *is* some chance that two GUID values could be the same.

Comment: To be more precise, `Random` is seeded with the current system time by default. Since iterations of a simple loop are very fast, all `Random` instances in that loop will have the same seed.

Comment: In addition to that adding a seed to the Random instance wouldn't hurt: `Random rnd = new Random("Integer Seed for random number generation");` possibly basing it off the day of year against the time of day or whatever dynamic value.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! :

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n",Enumerable.Repeat(0, 1000).Select(i => rand.Next(0,2) == 1 ? "Tails" : "Heads").GroupBy(i=>i).Select(g=> g.Key + " " + g.Count())));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```