# Random gives always the same value

Tags: c#

I am creating a simple class to generate fake lorem ipsum text so I have:

```
public static class LoremIpsumGenerator {

  private static Random _random = new Random();

  private static String _lorem = Constants.LoremIpsumText;
  private static IEnumerable<String> _words = _lorem.ToWordList();

  public static String GetText(Int32 totalLength = 200, Int32? paragraphLength = null) {

  IList<String> words = _words.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();

  String text = String.Empty;
  String paragraph = _lorem.Substring(0, 12);

  Int32 index = 0;

  while (text.Length < totalLength) {

    //Int32 a = (paragraphLength == null ? _random.Next(20, 80) : paragraphLength.Value);

    Int32 limit = _random.Next(20, 80);

    while (paragraph.Length < limit) {

      paragraph += (String.IsNullOrEmpty(paragraph) ? words[index].ToFirstLetterUppercase() : words[index].ToLower()) + " ";        

      index++;

      if (index > words.Count)
        index = 0;

    }

    paragraph = paragraph.TrimEnd();
    text += paragraph + ". ";
    paragraph = String.Empty;

  }

  return text;

  } // GetText

} // LoremIpsumGenerator
```

The problem is in line:

```
Int32 l = (paragraphLength == null ? _random.Next(20, 80) : paragraphLength.Value);
```

It gives me almost always the same value ... For example I got:

```
21, 21, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47
or 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50
```

Does anyone know how to prevent this?

**UPDATE**

```
public static class LoremIpsumGenerator {

  private static Random _random = new Random();

  private static String _lorem = Constants.LoremIpsumText;
  private static IEnumerable<String> _words = _lorem.ToWordList();

  public static String GetText(Int32 totalLength = 200, Int32? paragraphLength = null) {

  IList<String> words = _words.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();

  String text = String.Empty;
  String paragraph = _lorem.Substring(0, 12);

  Int32 index = 0;

  while (text.Length < totalLength) {

    Int32 limit = _random.Next(20, 80);

    while (paragraph.Length < limit) {

      paragraph += (String.IsNullOrEmpty(paragraph) ? words[index].ToFirstLetterUppercase() : words[index].ToLower()) + " ";        

      index++;

      if (index > words.Count)
        index = 0;

    }

    paragraph = paragraph.TrimEnd();
    text += paragraph + ". ";
    paragraph = String.Empty;

  }

  } // GetText

} // LoremIpsumGenerator
```

Comment: Do you know that `paragraphLength` is null?

Comment: @Jonesopolis: That question is a bit different--the asker in that question is instantiating a new `Random` inside the loop, which this code is not doing.

Comment: Is more than one thread calling `GetText` at the same time, `Random` is not thread safe and you could potentially be calling `Next` from multiple threads which can break it and cause it to keep returning the same number.

Comment: @BenGlasser I dobut it is that either, he is getting the same number every time, that is a little bigger problem than trying to get a result with no duplicates.

Comment: Agree with @ScottChamberlain, indeed it's a very strange case if really is what is happening to the user.

Comment: @Lee yes, paragraphLength is null

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain I am calling this from a test method

Comment: @Miguel, In your case I would split the inline if on two lines to be able to debug it more easily, also add the code where you checked these values are being the same to see if there is the problem.

Comment: Show what you are doing inside `// loop code`, the problem must be there because I don't see any issues anywhere else.

Comment: this question scream this comic : http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/wp-content/uploads/121411_1611_SecureRando1.png

Comment: MWAHAHAHA, very good @DavidHaim

Comment: @ScottChamberlain See the update ... I just added my loop code ... And simplified my code with Int32 limit = _random.Next(20, 80); ... On the second while I added a debug breakpoint and got 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70 ...

Comment: Are you sure the `Random` you are using is `System.Random` and not some other class named `Random` from some other DLL you have referenced or in another file in your project? That is the only thing I can think of. I would reccomend trying to simplifing the problem as much as you can, get rid of all of the text stuff and see how simple you can make the problem before Random starts working correctly again. then go back one step and post that program.

Comment: @Miguel seems like this describe your problem: you cannot generate random number instance [too fast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654887/random-next-returns-always-the-same-values)

Comment: sorry to ask, but where are you adding your breakpoint? In `while (paragraph.Length < limit)`? If so, then you are not iterating over the outer "while", but on the inside, and you have not yet generated the next number.

Comment: I copy-pasted your updated code and ran it on my machine. I looked at `limit` on each run and I get different numbers on each call. Are you sure you aren't passing an unchanging `paragraphLength` when you call `GetText`?

Comment: Deleted previous comment: Indeed, I also get a different random number every time. Maybe you are looking at the debugger the wrong way: you won't get a different number for every time the inner loop gets executed. Only when you do the outer loop will you get a different number.

Comment: I restarted Visual Studio a tested it again and now it seems to work fine ... Is this even possible?