# Trying to create a unique random number. If number exits in database generate again and add value to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, random

I am trying to create a unique random number. If the random number exists in the database, loop through the block of code again until it finds a number that does not exist. Save value to database. Any help on this would be great. Thank you.

```
public IHttpActionResult BookMatch(int id)
{
    Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();

    var user = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var getuser = db.AspNetUsers.Find(user);
    var match = db.Matches.Find(id);

    Random rnd = new Random();
    var peg = rnd.Next(match.PegRangeMin, match.PegRangeMax);

    var alreadyExists = db.Pegs.Any(x => x.MatchId == match.Id && x.PegNo == peg);

    if (alreadyExists == true)
    {
        //do something
    }

    var result = new Booked()
    {

        MatchId = id,
        BookerId = user,
        TicketNo = guid.ToString(),
        //pegNo = randompeg
    };

    db.Bookeds.Add(result);
    db.SaveChanges();

    if (result == null)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    var getmatch = db.Matches.Find(id);

        var body = "<p>Email From: {0} ({1}) </p>" +
                   "<h3>Match Booking Confirmation:</h3>" +
                   "<b>Ticket Number:</b><p> {2} </p>" +
                   "<b>Venue:</b><p> {3} </p>" +
                   "<b>date and time:</b><p>{4}</p>";

        var message = new MailMessage();
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress(getuser.Email));
        message.From = new MailAddress("nicholas.mciver@Activeplan.co.uk");
        message.Subject = "Matchbooker Confirmation Email";
        message.Body = string.Format(body, getuser.GetFullName(), getuser.Email,
            result.TicketNo, getmatch.Fishery.Name, getmatch.DateTime);
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;

        using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }

    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: You can make a recursive function (a function that calls itself). Generate a number and check the DB. If the generated number exists in the DB, call your function recursively. If it does not exist, you can insert into the DB and return out of the function.

Comment: You either loop or you use recursion (like @NolanBradshaw suggested).  Currently you throw an exception which will prevent retries.

Comment: You will get a race if just after you determined that a number is still available, another user adds this very number. Depending on the DBMS you use, it might be better to use a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to do the number generation and the check in a `while (true)` loop:

```
int peg;

while (true)
{
    peg = rnd.Next(match.PegRangeMin, match.PegRangeMax);

    var alreadyExists = db.Pegs.Any(x => x.MatchId == match.Id && x.PegNo == peg);

    if (!alreadyExists) break;
}
```

This is not perfect because in case that all possible numbers are taken, the loop will never break. But this may not be a problem in practice, provided that the min-max range is sufficiently large.

Comment: Thanks for this I was able to accomplish what I was looking to do  with a continue rather than a break. If the number exists in the database then continue until if finds a number that isn't in the database. I then created a recursive function with this method. Thanks for your help. @Theodor Zoulias

Comment: @NicholasMcIver you have probably a `break` somewhere, otherwise the loop would continue for ever. :-)

Comment: What if I make the booking impossible in the UI if all possible numbers exist with the matchId?

Comment: @NicholasMcIver OK, you have a `return` instead  of `break`. :-) Btw I suggest to move the creation of the `Random` outside of the loop. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654887/random-next-returns-always-the-same-values) for an explanation why.

Comment: @NicholasMcIver if all numbers are taken, then you have a big problem. The loop will spin forever!